# Deleting multiple objects within JSON

Tags: python, json

```
name_list = [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Johan'}, {'name': 'John'}]

    for i in xrange(len(name_list)):
        if name_list[i]["name"] == "John":
            del name_list[i]
```

After the first time recognizing John, it deletes that object but breaks out of the function. How can I continue traversing till the end and delete every single JSON object which has John as name?

Many thanks guys!

Comment: You are asking about how to traverse a list while deleting items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't remove items form a sequence you are currently iterating over. It's much safer to build a new dictionary without the elements you don't want:

```
new_list = [d for d in name_list if d['name'] != 'John']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you are looking for. Trick is to delete from the end of the list first (highest index).

```
name_list = [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Johan'}, {'name': 'John'}]

for index, i in enumerate(reversed(name_list)):
    if i['name'] == 'John':
        del name_list[index]
```